# Add HTML attribute to intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add my custom HTML attribute to VS's intellisense? Say, `data-bind` is very useful and would be great not to write the whole attribute name again and again.

Comment: @GôTô, unfortunately not.